# Error when adding views programmatically to a custom layout (not using inflate function)

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I've used custom layouts in the past, but so far only with an xml layout file to describe my child views and usign the `layoutInflater.inflate` function.

This time i would like to **not** use an xml layout file, and add all the views i want to my custom layout programmatically. What I do is:

```
public class myLayout extends FrameLayout  {
    private Context c;
    private LayoutParams webViewLayoutParams;

    public myLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    c = context;
    initMyWebView();
    addToLayout(mywebView,mywebViewLayoutParams);
}

    private void initMyWebView() {
    Log.d("init", "init webview");
    mywebView=new WebView(c);
    mywebViewLayoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);


}
   private void addToLayout(View view, LayoutParams params) {
    Log.d("init", "adding child view");
    this.addView(view, params);

}
}
```

My custom layout is only "called" in my main activity layout file

```
<com.mypackage.myLayout
    android:id="@+id/myLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

When i launch the app on my terminal, it just crashes right away

```
09-07 11:17:25.035: E/ActivityThread(17250): Failed to inflate
09-07 11:17:25.035: E/ActivityThread(17250): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.mypackage.myLayout
09-07 11:17:25.035: E/ActivityThread(17250):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
09-07 11:17:25.035: E/ActivityThread(17250):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
etc...
```

I guess I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Is there something I am doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I finally found the problem. It was coming from the admob lib that i had just included in the project, I was not even using it! External JARs must be in the libs directory too since ADT17...Hope this helps if someone runs into the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

in your `initMyWebView()` you assign two variables new values(`mywebView` and  `mywebViewLayoutParams`), but where are these initiated? Maybe you only need to init those variables.

I see that you init `webViewLayoutParams` but not `mywebViewLayoutParams`

Comment: These are typos, i changed the names to post here and just forgot to add "my" here. I edited my question with the solution. It was coming from an external JAR... Thanks anyway ! :)